# Google chart error - All series on a given axis must be of the same data type×

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Below is the javascript code used to populate the data for google chart - line chart.

```
  //This function is used to bind the user data to chart
function LMTServerDashboardChart(data, Zaxis) {
    debugger
    $("#LMT_CompanyUsage").show();
    var dataArray = [
    ['Date and Hour(s)',Zaxis, 'Company']
    ];
    //$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    //    dataArray.push([item.Date.replace(" 12:00:00 AM", ""), item.noofuser]);
    //});
    if (document.getElementById("PeakUsage").checked)
    {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            dataArray.push([item.Date.replace(" 12:00:00 AM", ""), item.noofuser]);
        });
    }
    else {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            dataArray.push([item.DateTime, item.noofuser, item.Company]);
        });
```

[Google chart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpq9A.png)

Here as mentioned in the image below I am getting an error '
**All series on a given axis must be of the same data type×'**

As I wanted to show different line bar for a different company, As you can see there two different companies in the first image attached.

I am looking for something like below image.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8aU6.png)
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chart will use the values in the first column of the data table as the x-axis,
and each additional column as the y-axis (no strings)

to get the requested chart, the array will need to be structured as follows...

```
[
  ['Date and Hour(s)', 'Company Name 1', 'Company Name 2'],
  ['22.5.2018:1', 1, 1],  // <-- values for companies
  ['22.5.2018:2', 2, 2],
]
```

Comment: Yes. But How do I convert it into above format since the data is dynamic and rows need to be replaced by column? @whiteHat

Comment: Thanks, @whitehat.Its achieved.